# Pass Prop to Child component onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Depending on which link is clicked, I would like to update the img src in the     `MapImage` Component

```
import React from 'react'
import NavLink from './NavLink'

var MapImage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <img src={'./img/' + this.props.img + '.png'} />
  }
});

export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
    return { img: '1' }
  },

  loadImage: function () {
    this.setState({
        img: this.props.img
    });
  },  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Maps</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><NavLink onClick={this.loadImage} to="/maps/firstfloor" img='1'>1st Floor</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink onClick={this.loadImage} to="/maps/secondfloor" img='2'>2nd Floor</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink onClick={this.loadImage} to="/maps/thirdfloor" img='3' >3rd Floor</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
        {this.props.children}
        <MapImage img={this.state.img} />
      </div>     
    )
  }
})
```

The image src is updated to `./img/undefined.png`

Comment: And where's your problem?

Comment: What's the specific issue? You're passing the state correctly to `MapImage`.  Are you getting errors?

Comment: sorry--the img value is undefined

Comment: Where is this error being thrown? Is it in the `loadImage` function? `this.props.img` in this function assumes props are being passed into this component from another parent component (or state container if you're using one). I'm assuming you're trying to access the `img={/*Number*/}` from the `NavLink` component `onClick`? If so you'll have to bind it or pass it to `loadImage`.

Comment: No Error thrown the src just gets set to 'img/undefined.png'. Interestingly, on the second click the parameter does get set, but the image path is now http://localhost:8080/maps/img/secondfloor.png  instead of http://localhost:8080/img/secondfloor.png (root directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have that image value in the props when you're doing:

```
this.setState({
    img: this.props.img
});
```

Try to pass a parameter to the `loadImage` function, and use it in the `setState`:

```
// in JSX
onClick={ function () { this.loadImage(1); } }

// function
loadImage: function (img) {
    this.setState({
        img: img
    });
}
```

For each NavLink image.

In general, I'd recommend having an array and iterating over it, like:

```
var images = [{
   value: 'firstfloor',
   text: '1st Floor' 
}, 
{ ... // other objects }]
```

And then iterate like this (or change values depending on your logic):

```
{ 
   images.map((image, index) => {
      return (
         <li>
             <NavLink 
                   onClick={ function () { this.loadImage(index); } } 
                   to={ '/maps/' + image.value }
                   img={ index }>
                 { image.text }
             </NavLink>
         </li>
      );
   });
}
```